# How to reliably extract property, content from meta tag?

Tags: python, html, string, parsing

I have eg. the following lines of HTML.  I need to extract and get a list of `og:image` and the `content` property.  Problem is, that is if I do as simple string.split(), the results will not be the same for lines below, as second line has many spaces in `content` value.

How can I reliably process such lines of strings and get a list like:
`['og:image', 'http....whatever.jpg']` and same for second line?

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://google.com/example.jpg"/>
 <meta property="og:title" content="Fant over 300 falske personer i skattelistene"/>
```

Edit:
I'm parsing like thus now:

```
tree = etree.HTML( xml )
m = tree.xpath("//meta[@property]")
for i in m:
    og = etree.tostring( i )
    print og # <meta property="og:image" content="http://google.com/example.jpg"/>
```

Perhaps there's a way to get the content/property into a list directly with XPath?

Comment: You can't use a proper HTML parser instead?

Comment: I've added the parser I'm using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of casting your elements back to string, just grab the attributes through the `attrib` mapping of each element:

```
for i in m:
    print (i.attrib['property'], i.attrib['content'])
```